# Portable way to split an external variable containing newlines in awk?

Tags: awk, posix

Consider these `awk` commands:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
awk 'BEGIN { print split("X\nX",a,"\n") }'
awk -v s=$'X\nX' 'BEGIN { print split(s,a,"\n") }'
```

**Results:**

- Linux:

```
2
2
```

- macOS, FreeBSD:

```
2
/usr/bin/awk: newline in string X
X... at source line 1
```

- Solaris:

```
2
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk: file "(null)": line 1: Newline in string
  Context is:
>>>     X
>>>             <<<
```

Is there a way to work around that?

---

**Edit:**

There's not even the need to use an external variable, the following will also fail in all `awk` implementations but the GNU one:

```sh
awk 'BEGIN { s = "X\nX"; print split(s,a,"\n") }'
```

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN { s = "X\nX"; print split(s,a,"\n") }'` works fine on mac. Or even `awk -v s="X\nX" 'BEGIN { print split(s,a,"\n") }'` works fine on mac

Comment: @anubhava Are you using BigSur or Monterey? It seems to be fixed on BSD then.

Comment: yes, I am using `Monterey`

Comment: Both also works on Oracle Solaris 11.4 (I previously tested 11.3). Never mind, It's all fixed now ^^ I won't delete the question as it may be interesting to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**POSIX awk does not allow physical newlines in string values**.

When you use C/BASH string notation like `$'a\nb'` then any POSIX compliant awk implementation will fail.

Even with gnu-awk, when you enable `posix` option following error will be returned:

```sh
awk --posix -v s=$'X\nX' 'BEGIN { print split(s,a,"\n") }'
awk: fatal: POSIX does not allow physical newlines in string values
```

However if you remove `$'...'` notation then error will not be there:

```sh
awk --posix -v s="X\nX" 'BEGIN { print split(s,a,"\n") }'
2
```

Comment: I'm actually surprised that last one works since `-v` by design expands escape sequences and so would turn the string `\n` into a linefeed character. I thought you'd need to use ENVIRON[] or ARGV[].